Confusion about relation between $\infty$-categories and model categories
Let $\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{D}$ be simplicial, combinatorial model categories. Let $F: \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ be a simplicial functor that preserves cofibrations. Say for simplicity all objects of $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ are fibrant. Now $F$ induces a functor between the homotopy coherent nerves $N(\mathcal{C}^o)\to N(\mathcal{D}^o)$, where $\mathcal{C}^o$-denotes the simplicial subcategory of bifibrant objects. In Higher Algebra Construction 1.3.4.18 we get an equivalence $\mathcal{C}^c[W_C^{-1}] \simeq N(\mathcal{C}^o)$, from the 1-category of cofibrant objects of $\mathcal{C}$ Dwyer-Kan localized at the weak-equivalences of $\mathcal{C}$. So, we should get an induced functor $\tilde{F}: \mathcal{C}^c[W_C^{-1}] \to \mathcal{D}^c[W_D^{-1}]$.
Now, in the case that $F$ doesn't preserve weak-equivalences between cofibrant objects, this $\tilde{F}$ must do something weird. As a functor between $\infty$-categories it must preserve weak-equivalences. In particular, for $X,Y\in \mathcal{C}^c$. The  mapping space $\text{map}(FX, FY) $ computed in the $\infty$-category $N(\mathcal{D}^o)[W_D^{-1}]$ must somehow not have the homotopy type of $F(\text{Hom}(X,Y))$. I believe, when $F$ preserves weak-equivalences or is a left Quillen functor, then $\text{map}(FX, FY) \simeq F(\text{Hom}(X,Y))$ and this should hold naturally in some sense. But for this I couldn't find a reference.

It seems to me like a simplicial functor between simplicial model categories which preserves bifibrant objects automatically preserves weak equivalences of bifibrant objects. Recall that weak equivalences of bifibrant objects are the same as homotopy equivalences (in the model categorical sense). Being a simplicial model category (roughly) is asserting that the homotopy theory obtained using the simplicial enrichment matches the internal notion of homotopy on the bifibrant objects. In other words, for bifibrant objects $f,g$ being homotopy inverse is the same as saying the composites $fg$ and $gf$ are in the same path component as the identity. This property is certainly preserved by simplicial functors, and so we've (sketchily) demonstrated the claim.
